# Having trouble changing a value from null to not null in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, null

I am attempting to change salary to not null. My syntax is below.

[And an image of the table I am trying to modify]

[image: 1]

.Thank you!

mysql>

```
alter table temp modify salary varchar(10) not null;
```

> ERROR 1138 (22004): Invalid use of NULL value

Comment: This works in DB Fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34f13bc5a8141fea8375f27d679fd217.

Comment: if there is already a NULL value then you can not change to NOT NULL. If you want to change to NOT NULL then make sure that there should not be any NULL values. You can update NULL Values to 0 then try to make NOT NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You already have NULL data in the `salary` column so MySQL can't apply a NOT NULL constraint to it.

Make sure all the rows contain some data in the `salary` column (even if that data is 0) and try again